# Is number input type possible in jqGrid inline editing?

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to use number input type (with arrows) in jqGrid while inline editing?
Like here:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7skq.jpg)

jqGrid  version 4.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in version 4.5.4 (as far as I remember) this is possible, if you define custom input type. In the definition use the type=number when you define the element. Custom input type are described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#options_and_description) (look at edittype custom and the example)